# F# Excel UsedRange is not Defined

Tags: excel, f#, vsto, office-interop

Error: "The field, constructor or member 'UsedRange' is not defined".

Code excerpts:

```
open Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
open Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel // Onorio's excellent suggestion didn't fix code until this line was added.
// Once the above line was added, Onorio's suggestion worked,
// but now F# says "The field, constructor or member 'EntireColumn' is not defined".

let xl = ApplicationClass()
xl.Workbooks.OpenText(...
let wb = xl.Workbooks.Item(1)
let ws = wb.ActiveSheet :?> Worksheet // Per Onorio's suggestion.

ws.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit()
// "The field, constructor or member 'EntireColumn' is not defined".

// Here's another example of UsedRange now working,
// but Properties and Methods of UsedRange not working:
// (uniqueID is simply a Boolean set earlier based on ini file values)
if uniqueID then
   xl.Range("A1").EntireColumn.Insert() |> ignore
   xl.Range("A1").Value <- "UniqueID"
   xl.Range("A2").Value <- 1
   xl.Range("A2").AutoFill(xl.Range("A2:A" + ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count),
                           XlAutoFillType.xlFillSeries) |> ignore
// Here it's "The field, constructor or member 'Rows' is not defined".
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't mean to be petulant but if my answer is the solution to your problem would you please accept it?  If it's not, maybe you could expand on your question?

Comment: And I don't mean to be negligent. I simply haven't had a chance to implement your suggestion to prove that it is the correct solution yet. I hope to do so first thing Monday morning. As always, I appreciate your expertise of F# and functional programming! Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: If you're running this from the FSI, I'm really surprised you don't need to include a reference to the Excel assembly--like so: #r "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel"  If you've not done that, you need to. None of the other stuff will work without that line at the start.

Comment: I'm not running it from the FSI, I just pulled up the FSI to find the F# version number. I prototyped the app in F# (processing text files), then rewrote it in VB for the additional Excel functionality the user requested, and compiled and deployed that version. But if I can get past these F# stumbles, I'd like to compile and deploy the F# instead.

Comment: Jeff--so you're trying to build this in Visual Studio right?  If so, make sure the project references the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel assembly. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(v=vs.100).aspx (for VS 2010 but click "Other Versions" at the top and find your version).

Comment: The project does indeed reference Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. I've begun a [new post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039153/f-excel-usedrange-has-no-properties-or-methods) for this issue, as the original question has been answered perfectly. Thank you, Onorio!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
let wb = xl.Workbooks.Item(1)
let actSheet = wb.ActiveSheet :?> Worksheet  //downcast obj to Worksheet
actSheet.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit()
```

`wb.ActiveSheet` returns an "obj" and you need to downcast it to a Worksheet in order for the `UsedRange` method to resolve correctly.

Comment: Well, adding this code did not help, until I added open Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel to the module, but now I have a new problem: "The field, constructor or member EntireColumn is not defined". Neither is Sort, or Rows. I **really** want to do this in F# and not VB. As always, thanks, Onorio!

Comment: Which version of F# are you working with?  Which version of Excel? This works just fine on my machine so it seems likely to be some sort of infrastructure difference.

Comment: Ooh, I don't want to hear that. F# 2.0 Interactive build 4.0.40219.1. Excel 2010 (Version 14.0.6123.5001). I've gotten the idea that the version of Office our company uses is built specifically for our company. If you don't have any further ideas, I'll go ahead and mark this as the answer, assuming that it works for most users. Let me know. Thanks again!

Comment: I've been testing with Excel 2010 and F# 2.0 so that shouldn't be the difference.  Edit the question to post _exactly_ the updated code you're using so I can be sure I'm not missing something.

Comment: May also be something about the Excel file you're using.  Try creating a new Excel file and try the code on a brand new file and see what happens.

Comment: I'll update the original post with some more code. But I haven't even gotten to the point of using an Excel file. These are compile-time errors, so I can't run the code.

Comment: Marking this as the answer, as it answered my original question.

Comment: I've begun a [new post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039153/f-excel-usedrange-has-no-properties-or-methods) for this issue, as the original question has been answered perfectly.