# F# Excel UsedRange has no Properties or Methods

Tags: excel, f#, vsto, office-interop

This is a continuation of the discussion begun on [F# Excel UsedRange is not Defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12956517/f-excel-usedrange-is-not-defined/12957422#12957422), which has been solved by down-casting the ActiveSheet object to a Worksheet. Upon doing that, however, I was presented with a new problem: UsedRange exposes no properties or methods other than the standard object methods.

My solution has references to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel and Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.v4.0.Utilities.

```
open Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
open Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel

let xl = ApplicationClass()
xl.Workbooks.OpenText(fileName)
let wb = xl.Workbooks.Item(1)
let ws = wb.ActiveSheet :?> Worksheet

ws.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit()
// "The field, constructor or member 'EntireColumn' is not defined".

ws.UsedRange.Sort(xl.Range(sortKey1), XlSortOrder.xlAscending)
// "The field, constructor or member 'Sort' is not defined".

xl.Range("A2").Value <- 1
xl.Range("A2").AutoFill(xl.Range("A2:A" + ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count),
                        XlAutoFillType.xlFillSeries) |> ignore
// "The field, constructor or member 'Rows' is not defined".

ws.UsedRange.
// Intellisense shows only default object members, e.g. Equals, GetEnumerator, etc.
```

I can use Range with no problem:

```
xl.Range("A1").EntireColumn.Insert() |> ignore
```

UsedRange is recognized as a Range. Down-casting to Range, Visual Studio warns me: "This type test or downcast will always hold".

Range works.
UsedRange is recognized as Range.
Therefore, UsedRange should work.
But it doesn't. I'm left with contradiction.

Visual Studio 2010 Premium, F# 2.0.

I appreciate any insight offered. Thanks.

Comment: That is pretty weird. It works fine on my machine - see details in the answer - not sure what could be the difference.

Comment: As Tomas said, this should be working for you--I am extremely puzzled that it isn't.  Insure you're referencing the correct versions of the DLL's because, if memory serves, there are multiple versions of the DLL's available all having the same name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure your F# project references the correct versions of all the necessary interop assemblies? I just tried your code in F# script file and I can see members of `UsedRange` fine after adding the following lines:

```
#r "office.dll"
#r "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll"
```

I can see members like `EntireColumn` and `Sort` and it only complains that one line in the snippet is attempting to use `+` on string and integer:

```
xl.Range("A2").AutoFill(xl.Range("A2:A" + (string ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count)), 
                        XlAutoFillType.xlFillSeries) |> ignore
```

I tried this in Visual Studio 2010 as a script file and also in a new project (after adding the two references, it seems to be working okay).  I added reference to the `dll` that is installed under "Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA" in the Visual Studio installation directory.

Comment: Well, you two convinced me that it was my project that was confused. So I just removed the references to Office and Interop.Excel and added them again. Viola. Everything is beautiful again. Thank you both so much for your time and efforts!

Comment: Glad to hear you resolved this Jeff.  Welcome to the F# community :-)